# object detection

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
Sorry for my stupid question. :)
I watched a video on youtube about object detection and roboearth. I want to use that software but I do not know the steps I have to take. Can someone PLEASE just tell me the steps I have to take. I only need this object detection and and I dont use ros generally. I have kienct and I really need this software for my project. So please someone tell me the steps from the scratch.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182473/object-detection/) by [farhad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19387/farhad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you to install ROS first and to take a look at ROS beginner tutorials to have an idea how ROS generally works.

> http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

Finishing the beginner tutorials shouldn't take you more than one day of your time. Once you have some basic understanding of ROS, check this tutorial : `

> http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack/Tutorials/Using%20recorded%20models%20for%20object%20detection

it explains how to use roboearth with a kinect for object recognition. But first you should also install those ROS packages/stacks

> OpenNI : http://wiki.ros.org/openni  Necessary accessing the data recorded by your Kinect

> RoboEarth http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack Contains useful packages for accessing RoboEarth functionalities

Steps needed to install those packages are explained each package's page. This might be a slow solution that could take few days of your time but I think that the time invested in learning ROS basics is definitely worth it.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2